# Why did Spring Data JPA save method didn't validate straight away?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot (1.3.3.RELEASE) with Spring Data and Bean Validation on a project and I found an unexpected (at least to me) behaviour. I have an User entity and its UserRepository (an interface that extends JpaRepository). When I make a call like this:

```
userRepository.save(user);
logger.info("User saved with id", user.getId());
```

On a new and INvalid user, logger is called and shows that the user received an id. Even though nothing gets persisted and ConstraintViolationException is thrown at the end, after logging.

But if I change to:

```
userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
logger.info("User saved with id", user.getId());
```

ConstraintViolationException is thrown right away and the logger line never gets reached.

This second behaviour, where the exception is thrown before the logger, is what I believe it would have to happen when I call userRepository.save() method.

What is wrong? Something about my project? Or my understanding on how bean validation is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that triggering validation from within the data access layer is both bad design and a fundamentally bad idea. Doing so basically means that all code that handed you down the instance to save (and fail eventually) and that instance has been broken (in an invalid state) all the time. If that hasn't caused some intermediate business logic to fail, fingers crossed!

This approach usually works for *very* simple CRUD scenarios as basically no intermediary can fail if e.g. a field is `null` but shouldn't be etc. But as soon as you start to add some logic in between those errors will already break your logic (e.g. something expecting an email address to be of the correct format, being not null etc.).

I'd rather recommend to build a strong domain model that fundamentally prevents objects from getting into invalid state and adding a mapping layer *very* close to where the user input is received so that you basically discover missing validations by exceptions being thrown from that mapping step.

JSR-303 can then be used in the layer accepting the potentially tainted user data. But it's definitely something you should not use in your domain model.

Comment: a rich domain layer won't be using the same objects to persist that came in from your "tainted" source. Those objects will be DTO's. There is nothing about a "rich domain model" that prescribes that you can't use tools like the validation api, and that using them means an anaemic model. It's still a great tool for certain kinds of checks to make sure a developer didn't forget something.

Comment: I think you're looking at from the wrong side. It's not about how the data gets into the system, but in which way a string model is persisted. The question is if you want to use a separate persistence model (copy the domain model into persistence DTOs) or use a persistent model (add metadata to your domain model to allow the persistence layer to persist it as is). In either case, there's no room for validation in the persistence layer, as the domain model is supposed to enforce the business invariants already.

Comment: > There is nothing about a "rich domain model" that prescribes that you can't use tools like the validation api.

There is. The use of the validation API requires the code it's used in to be able to take invalid values (@Email String email). That's not a responsibility a domain model should be overloaded with. Using proper value objects, you can assert objects to always be in a valid state once constructed. The validation API is fine for DTOs that capture web input, JSON etc. but it's got no place anywhere below that layer.

Comment: I disagree, I think it has its uses validating layers below that too. Alternatives include writing a lot more code than is necessary. I mean, you can write everything yourself if you want all the time. Throw the baby out with the bath water. Honestly right now I'm using it to validate that the id field of the opaque strongly typed id class (that DDD people recommend) is not null. Why? because JPA makes me have no arg constructors... but I can make spring data automatically validate this on flush (apparently). The alternative is what? write hibernate hooks...?

Comment: you could argue it's not part of my domain model, you'd probably be right, but that doesn't mean the validation library has no place beneath your web service boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your flush strategy and Identity Generator the actual insert into DB may (and in your case it does) happen later. And in case of Hibernate it validates right before insert/update/delete (which in your case are postponed). See the sources of `BeanValidationEventListener` and its methods `onPreInsert()`, `onPreUpdate()` and `onPreDelete()`.